# Insert command on row from .SelectedRow

Tags: c#, sql, database, select, sql-insert

I have a Selected Row and now I wish to place Cell 2 into a table, there are no bugs in my code yet it is not updating the Data Base with the newly selected value one I button click, could somebody advise me if I am doing it correctly.

**Code**

```
 protected void Button_adduser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\ASPNetDB.mdb;Persist Security Info=True");
    {
        da.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO UserProfile (UserName) VALUES (@UserName)", conn);
        {
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Add_Usertoprof.SelectedRow);
        }
        conn.Open();

        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

}

I am getting this error on click

Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Comment: what is `Add_Usertoprof` ? and what actually you are trying to do ?

Comment: Add_Usertoprof is a select value i have running. so the idea A user signs up the i add (By selecting) the user to my table UserProfile so they now have a profile

Comment: i mean  `Add_Usertoprof.SelectedRow` ,are you selecting from datatable , gridview i mean what control is it, can you check `Add_Usertoprof.SelectedRow` value?

Comment: its selecting from a grid view populated from a database

Comment: You need to get value from `SelectedRow` try the code below i haven't tested yet though.

Comment: @Beep In that case you're trying to set a GridViewRow object in your INSERT which will fail. Use `Add_Usertoprof.SelectedRow.Cells[your column position index].Text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
da.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO UserProfile (UserName) VALUES (@UserName)", conn);
        {
          string usrName =  Convert.ToString(Add_Usertoprof.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text); //whatever your cell num is 
          da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", usrName);
        }
        conn.Open();

        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Ahh I understand, was thinking there was a way to point to the cell. thank you